# If $x^*(-t)=x(t)$ then $X(\omega)$ is a real-valued function.

Tags: fourier-analysis

So I was trying to prove/disprove the following claim:
If $x^*(-t)=x(t)$ (where $^*$ denotes the complex conjugate) then the Fourier transform
$$X(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t) e^{-j \omega t}\, dt$$
is a real-valued function, assuming $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$.

I managed to "disprove" it, but I know there must be something wrong with my argument. I'm also pretty sure the claim is true because I can't find a counter-example.

Anyways, this is my "proof":
\begin{align*}
X^*(\omega) &= \left[\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\,dt \right]^*\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left[x(t)e^{-j\omega t}\right]^*dt\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^*(t)e^{j\omega t}\, dt\\
&= -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^*(-\tau)^{-j\omega\tau}\, d\tau\\
&= -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}\, d\tau\\
&= - X(\omega),
\end{align*}
and therefore $X(\omega)$ must be purely imaginary.

I know this can't be true, because given any real-valued even function $x(t)$, such as the normalized sinc function $x(t)=\frac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$, clearly satisfies $x^*(-t)=x(t)$, but $X(\omega)$ must be real-valued too.

This isn't homework, any help understanding what's wrong with my "proof" would be appreciated.

Comment: You didn't change your integral limits when mapping $t \mapsto - \tau$. So you should have $X^{*} = X$.

Comment: I don't quite understand, if $\tau = -t$, then $dt = -d\tau$, and $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^*(t)e^{j\omega t}\,dt = \lim_{T\to+\infty} \int_{-T}^{+T} x^*(t)e^{j\omega t}\,dt = -\lim_{T\to+\infty} \int_{-T}^{T} x^*(-\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}\,d\tau = -\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x(\tau)e^{-j\omega\tau}\,d\tau$, right?

Comment: OK so I worked it out with $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos x\, dx$, and to my surprise, I can't simply do $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos x\, dx = -\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos (-y)\, dy$ (because one is 2 and the other -2), even though $-\pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi/2 \implies -\pi/2 \leq -x=y \leq \pi/2$. I have no idea how I'm only realizing this now....... Thank you anyway.

Comment: Just to expand on my point, if $t = - \tau$ then as $t \to \infty, \tau \to - \infty$. Similarly, for $t \to \infty, \tau \to -(- \infty) = \infty$. So your integral will be of the form $$\int_{\infty}^{- \infty} - d \tau = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d \tau$$ not $$\int_{- \infty}^{ \infty} - d \tau$$